# when installing gems "Error: Permission denied rb_sysopen" Arch Linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, archlinux

I am trying to install rails and I have already got ruby

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]
```

when I run `gem install rails` I get

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/nokogiri-1.6.8/gem_make.out
```

then exactly the same thing if I try to install `nokogiri`

I'm new to ruby/rails.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are having a permissions issue attempting to open

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/nokogiri-1.6.8/gem_make.out
```

Running this will most likely install correctly, but you may want to fix whatever the permission issue is instead:

```
sudo gem install rails
```

Comment: yes Thank you. A simple `sudo chmod 777 -R /usr/lib/ruby/` did the job

Comment: What about Windows? I am getting permission denial when trying to run `gem install sass`

Comment: the sudo won't work on windows. To elevate to administrator privileges, launch your command prompt as admin by right clicking it and choosing "Run as Administrator" and then gem install sass will not give you a permissions error.