# Can't Install Rails on Mac OS Catalina

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, macos

I'm getting an error message that I can't find the solution for when I'm trying to install Rails v 6.1.1 on my new Mac machine (still on Catalina, not Big Sur)

I have rbenv and Homebrew installed and have updated to the latest version of Ruby (3.0.0). When I put out `which ruby` I get: `/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby`

Here's the error code I'm seeing in terminal when I run `gem install rails -v 6.1.1` (same error with `sudo` install):

```
 Building native extensions. This could take a while...
 ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

 current directory: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mimemagic-0.3.10/ext/mimemagic
 /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0 -rrubygems /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.0.0_1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/exe/rake RUBYARCHDIR\=/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-19/3.0.0/mimemagic-0.3.10 RUBYLIBDIR\=/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-19/3.0.0/mimemagic-0.3.10
 rake aborted!
 Could not find MIME type database in the following locations: ["/usr/local/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml", "/opt/homebrew/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml", "/opt/local/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml", "/usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml"]

 Ensure you have either installed the shared-mime-info package for your distribution, or
 obtain a version of freedesktop.org.xml and set FREEDESKTOP_MIME_TYPES_PATH to the location of that file.

 This gem might be installed as a dependency of some bigger package, such as rails, activestorage, axlsx or cucumber. While most of these packages use the functionality of this gem, some gems have included this gem by accident. Set USE_FREEDESKTOP_PLACEHOLDER=true if you are certain that you do not need this gem, and wish to skip the inclusion of freedesktop.org.xml.

 The FREEDESKTOP_PLACEHOLDER option is meant as a transitional feature, and will be deprecated in the next release.
 /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mimemagic-0.3.10/ext/mimemagic/Rakefile:15:in `locate_mime_database'
 /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mimemagic-0.3.10/ext/mimemagic/Rakefile:39:in `block in <top (required)>'
 Tasks: TOP => default
 (See full trace by running task with --trace)

 rake failed, exit code 1

 Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mimemagic-0.3.10 for inspection.
 Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-19/3.0.0/mimemagic-0.3.10/gem_make.out
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error today. I'll let you know what I find. There were new releases of the mimemagic gem today. The previous versions were yanked

Comment: ah, yeah I was seeing mentions of mimemagic in the error codes without knowing what that was referring to. thanks!

Comment: The solution here worked for me .... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69248078/mimemagic-install-error-could-not-find-mime-type-database-in-the-following-loc

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you want to have `brew` install this for you and you haven't updated `brew` in a while, I would recommend running:

```
HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 brew install shared-mime-info
```

I ran just

```
brew install shared-mime-info
```

And it updated a bunch of packages I didn't want it to and broke my ruby installation.

I like spickermann's solution too. It seems to be what the package maintainers want you to do.

Comment: Thanks C-RAD! In my attempts to figure out what was going on I had both rvm and rbenv installed and was having issues - but once I reset to rbenv and installed shared-mime-info, I was able to install Rails! huzzah!

Comment: This installs 10 millions of packages just to ... install one gem...

Answer (score 12):

Just install `shared-mime-info` on your computer. From the docs of the [mimemagic gem](https://github.com/mimemagicrb/mimemagic)

> You will require a copy of the Freedesktop.org shared-mime-info database to be available. If you're on Linux, it's probably available via your package manager, and will probably be in the location it's being looked for when the gem is installed.
>
> macOS users can install the database via Homebrew with 
> `brew install shared-mime-info`.
>
> Should you be unable to use a package manager you can obtain a copy of the needed file by extracting it from the Debian package. This process will also work on a Windows machine. [...]

### Or

you might want to consider installing [Rails `6.1.3.1`](https://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2021/3/26/marcel-upgrade-releases/) (instead of `6.1.1` in your command). That version was released to fix exactly the `mimemagic` issue that you are facing – just a couple of hours ago.

Comment: So I ran brew install shared-mime-info and then when I went to install rails, I got this error code instead:

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mimemagic-0.3.10/.gitignore

Comment: I think that's a separate issue but you can try prepending `sudo` to your install command. You may also want to `chmod` the gem directory https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38799427/when-installing-gems-error-permission-denied-rb-sysopen-arch-linux