# Heroku push rejected error: Failed to install gems via Bundler (probably caused by mimemagic)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I try to push my project on heroku and error message pop outs

```
git push heroku master


    remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-18 stack
    remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/ruby
    remote: -----> Ruby app detected
    remote: -----> Installing bundler 2.2.11
    remote: -----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
    remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
    remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.6.3
    remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.2.11
    remote:        Running: BUNDLE_WITHOUT='development:test' BUNDLE_PATH=vendor/bundle BUNDLE_BIN=vendor/bundle/bin BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT=1 bundle install -j4
    remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
    remote:        **Your bundle is locked to mimemagic (0.3.5), but that version could not be found**
    remote:        in any of the sources listed in your Gemfile. If you haven't changed sources,
    remote:        that means the author of mimemagic (0.3.5) has removed it. You'll need to update
    remote:        your bundle to a version other than mimemagic (0.3.5) that hasn't been removed
    remote:        in order to install.
    remote:        Bundler Output: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
    remote:        Your bundle is locked to mimemagic (0.3.5), but that version could not be found
    remote:        in any of the sources listed in your Gemfile. If you haven't changed sources,
    remote:        that means the author of mimemagic (0.3.5) has removed it. You'll need to update
    remote:        your bundle to a version other than mimemagic (0.3.5) that hasn't been removed
    remote:        in order to install.
    remote: 
    remote:  !
    remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
    remote:  !
    remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
    remote: 
    remote:  !     Push failed
    remote:  !
```

I guess the problem is caused by rails gem mimemagic's version is out of date so I try to update to the latest version, it still doesn't work.

Here's my ruby, Rails, mimemagic  version

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-darwin18]

rails -v
Rails 6.1.3.1

bundle info mimemagic
  * mimemagic (0.4.3)
```

information in Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1', '>= 6.1.0'
gem 'bundler', '~> 2.2', '>= 2.2.1.1'
gem 'mimemagic', '~> 0.4.3'
```

in Gemfile.lock

```
 mimemagic (~> 0.4.3)
```

Comment: have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66823608/cant-install-rails-on-mac-os-catalina

Comment: @honey Given the OP is not using MacOS, but trying to run on Heroku, that question doesn't seem relevant.

Answer (score 2):

run `bundle update mimemagic` worked for me

Comment: Stackoverflow is filled with such issues. Consider leaving a comment with a link to an already answered one.

Comment: My mimemagic is the latest version gem 'mimemagic', '~> 0.4.3'
but sadly it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Change version of mimemagic to 0.3.10 in your Gemfile

Mimemagic seems to be experiencing updates? hopefully will be fixed soon. Try changing mimemagic to previous version for now..

Gemfile:

```html
gem 'mimemagic', '~> 0.3.10'
```

Comment: Using mimemagic 0.3.10 (was 0.4.3)


gem 'mimemagic', '~> 0.3.10'

It's still the same error message pops out:
"Your bundle is locked to mimemagic (0.3.5), but that version could not be found
remote: in any of the sources listed in your Gemfile."

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Running `bundle update` will automatically update every dependency on your app to the latest version