# Error while attempting to download rails 5.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I am trying to go from rails 6 to rails 5.2.3 for a project. For some reason I can't figure out how to install rails 5.2.3. When enter gem install rails --version=5.2.3 into the terminal i get the following error:

Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
current directory: /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mimemagic-0.3.10/ext/mimemagic
```

/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/bin/ruby -I/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems -rrubygems /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/exe/rake RUBYARCHDIR=/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-18/2.7.0/mimemagic-0.3.10 RUBYLIBDIR=/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-18/2.7.0/mimemagic-0.3.10
rake aborted!
Could not find MIME type database in the following locations: ["/usr/local/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml", "/opt/homebrew/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml", "/opt/local/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml", "/usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml"]

Ensure you have either installed the shared-mime-info package for your distribution, or
obtain a version of freedesktop.org.xml and set FREEDESKTOP_MIME_TYPES_PATH to the location
of that file.

This gem might be installed as a dependency of some bigger package, such as rails, activestorage,
axlsx or cucumber. While most of these packages use the functionality of this gem, some gems have
included this gem by accident. Set USE_FREEDESKTOP_PLACEHOLDER=true if you are certain that you
do not need this gem, and wish to skip the inclusion of freedesktop.org.xml.

The FREEDESKTOP_PLACEHOLDER option is meant as a transitional feature, and will be deprecated in
the next release.

Tasks: TOP => default
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

rake failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mimemagic-0.3.10 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-18/2.7.0/mimemagic-0.3.10/gem_make.out

Any ideas what im doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't Install Rails on Mac OS Catalina](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66823608/cant-install-rails-on-mac-os-catalina)

Comment: A change in licensing for the mimemagic gem caused a lot of issues with Rails versions.  5.2.3 does not have an update that deals with it.  Suggest moving to Rails 5.2.4.6 which handles it.